# Python - Парсинг с помощью BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Вопрос такой:

Ищу нужный контент на странице с помощью BeautifulSoup, например:

```
td = tr.find('td', id='some_id')
```

Тут понятно, ищем тег `'td'` с `id = 'some_id'`

Но при попытке фильтрации по такому аттрибуту `'data-market-type'` (составленному через тире):

```
td = tr.find('td', data-market-type='some_value')
```

выдаёт ошибку:

> SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

Как отфильтровать по такому аттрибуту?

Answer (score 2):

Поиск через `find` (`td = tr.find('td', id='some_id')`) использует семантику языка, поэтому, через тире не сработает, т.к. просто нельзя создать переменную с тире – языком такое не разрешается

Попробуйте:

```
td = tr.find('td', {'data-market-type': 'some_value'})
```

Есть другой способ: метод `select` (или `select_one`):

```
td = tr.select_one('td#some_id')
    
# Если нужно по классу искать
td = tr.select_one('td.some_class')
```

`select` / `select_one` поиск делают через `css-селектор`, поэтому если вопросы по поиску возникают, то лучше не в документацию `BeautifulSoup` смотреть, а в документацию по `css-селекторам`

Comment: т.е. получается нужно сделать так 

tr.select_one('td[data-mutable-id=some_value]')

верно?

Comment: @user268874, ага. Кст, я добавил пример с find